# How to mock list inside mocked object with python unittest?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I'm trying to return a list from Mock object but can't get it to work.

That's the code:

```
def execute_call(model, payload):
    result = model.execute(payload)
    code = result[0]
```

Here's the test I have tried:

```
def test_get_code(self, session):
    execute_call = Mock()
    execute_call.return_value = ['123', '123', '123']
    session.return_value = Mock(execute=execute_call)
```

Result:

```
code = result[0]
TypeError: 'Mock' object does not support indexing
```

I can't figure out how to make result[0] to work. 'execute_call' should be mock, but the return_value would need to be a list.

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
def execute_call(model, payload):
    result = model.execute(payload)
    code = result[0]

def test_execute_call(self):
    mock_model = mock.MagicMock()
    mock_model.execute = mock.MagicMock(return_value=(a,b,c)
    self.execute_call(mock_model, payload)
    assert whatever
```

You need to pass the mock object into the function so it can be used.